# How to change *your* Linux password via a Bash script

Tags: bash, passwd

It's easy enough to change *another* user's password via a Bash script - just do `echo newpw | sudo passwd username` and bam, you're done. But if you run `echo newpw | passwd username` it doesn't work because it prompts you for your current password before letting you enter in your new password.

How to change *your* password via Bash?

Comment: Did you have to use `su` or `sudo` for your "change *another* user's password" example to work?

Comment: Only `root` can use `passwd username` for a different user. When you run `passwd` (without `username`) as `root` it does not ask for the old password (on my Ubuntu 19.10 system).

Comment: Yah - I was doing `sudo`. The question still stands tho lol

Comment: So did you have to enter your password in order to `sudo` to change another user's password?

Comment: Well, give it the current password then, `{ sleep .1; echo OLDPASSWORD; for i in 1 2; do sleep .1; echo Trump2020! ; done; } | passwd`. Use `... | script -c passwd /dev/null` if `passwd` wants to read from a tty. But you really shouldn't be doing that.  Better say what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 11):

You could use [chpasswd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/chpasswd.8.html).

```
sudo chpasswd <<<"neubert:newpass"
```

Comment: For all us newbies, can you help me understand the need for `<<<` here? The only indication towards this that I see from the man page is the quote "from standard input". I'm far from a bash expert so just curious how I would read this man page and know to use the above syntax?

Comment: @topher217 This is a `here-string` to provide input to a file descriptor (similar to a `here-document`) by default to STDIN or fd0. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings)

Comment: Thanks @JRFerguson. I also found [these examples](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chpasswd-command-in-linux-with-examples/) helpful. I'm not sure if I am wording this correctly, but now I understand that running `chpasswd` opens a kind of interactive STDIN terminal as opposed to expecting some string positional argument. You're idea of using a `here-string` makes the usage of `chpasswd` resemble the syntax of a single line positional argument. I also found reading the man page for `cat` and comparing the examples of using it with and without a file positional arg helpful.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to change the passwd of the current user, this should do as well:

```
echo -e "MyOldPasswd\nMyNewPasswd\nMyNewPasswd" | passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

That won't work with any halfway reasonable setup. Only root can change other user's passwords, via `passwd user` (it should prompt for the new password). To change your own password, do `passwd`, it should ask for the current password an then ask for the new one (and confirmation).

Allowing any random user to change other's passwords is a *huge* security problem.

Comment: Why "That won't work with any halfway reasonable setup" and "Allowing any random user to change other's passwords"? This answer is unrelated to the current question. The current question is about changing your password. That works. That is secure.

Comment: @ValerioBozz I'd disagree. If the premise is wrong then any expectation about an answer will also be wrong

Comment: @roaima Maybe we are on different premises. The user already said «I was doing sudo». So anwering «Only root can change» is not useful to the user. It seems the user is not interested in avoiding root. We don't need to say why root is necessary.

Comment: @ValerioBozz the OP seems confused about `sudo`. They demonstrate that they can use `sudo` to forcibly change any password without entering the old one, and then ask why (without `sudo`) they have to enter their current password before being able to change it. Secondly, I think there may be an English language confusion. Someone can use "your" to mean any of "your" (of you, to whom I'm speaking) or "someone" (possibly including "me" and "you", but also anyone else). I think the last sentence is intended to mean "How can I change my password without needing to know the previous one?"